# Using the Same Class to Store Data From Multiple Runs of a Function

Tags: c#, ajax, asp.net-mvc, class

On my project, I have an ajax method which triggers a function several times (all one the same run). For example, if the user presses a button, it triggers the Ajax and the function gets data for 10 seconds. After this, the user can press this button again and this will trigger the Ajax method again and will aquire more data for 10 and so forth. On each trigger, I have to store this data somehow and at the end of all the runs I will combine and store at my DB.

My problem is that If I create a class with all the runtimes, every time that I enter this function I reinitialize the class losing my previous data. So my idea at this point is something like:

I call a function this way:
Front end side:

```
function ReadsSerial() {
        $.ajax({
            url: "/Home/ReadsSerial",
            type: 'POST',
            data: { sintraining: gTrained },
            success: function (result) {
                alert(result.name);
            },
            error: function () {
                alert("error");
            }
        });
        return false;
};
```

And on my Back End I have a function like this:

```
[HttpPost]
        public ActionResult ReadsSerial(string sintraining)
        {
            try
            {
                sintraining = Int32.Parse(sintraining);
            }
            catch (FormatException)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"Unable to parse '{sintraining}'");
            }

                if (sintraining == 0)
                {
                    // Call the constructor that has no parameters.
                    HandGesturesStorage0 handGesturesStorage = new HandGesturesStorage0();
                    handGesturesStorage.HandGesture0 = all;
                }
                if (sintraining == 1)
                {
                    HandGesturesStorage1 handGesturesStorage = new HandGesturesStorage1();
                    handGesturesStorage.HandGesture1 = all;
                }
                if (sintraining == 2)
                {
                    HandGesturesStorage2 handGesturesStorage = new HandGesturesStorage2();
                    handGesturesStorage.HandGesture2 = all;
                }
```

And my classes are like this:

```
public class HandGesturesStorage0
{
    public string HandGesture0 { get; set; }
}

public class HandGesturesStorage1
{
    public string HandGesture1 { get; set; }
}

public class HandGesturesStorage2
{
    public string HandGesture2 { get; set; }
}
```

But I feel that it must be a better way! If I have 10 run times I will have to create 10 if elses and 10 classes. Any ideas?

Comment: *"I have to store this data somehow [...] I will combine and store at my DB"* - If you have a database, why not store the data there?

Comment: @David that's one idea that it may be the only solution. As I have to "massage" all the rounds of data/output and run analysis on this data, my idea was to read all this data, do everything that I need and save on the clean version on DB. Otherwise, I will have to save on the DB, get it back to do data manipulation, then add to the DB again the clean version. I will be adding unnecessary steps.

Comment: Have you considered just storing them in a dictionary of int, string kvp? Or just a list of strings and use the count to determine if it's at 10 yet etc.

Comment: You’re still creating new objects and throwing them away after. There’s many ways to handle this, session storage is one of them. But List<> is a good contender since you want dynamic amount of data. There’s no need for different classes for the exactly same data. You can instantiate a class infinite number of times.

Comment: @Sdyess and Sami yes, I think that a list of the strings is a good approach. My problem is that if I create this list inside my function (ReadsSerial) after I execute once, I loose the data of this list that I created before. For example, on the 2nd execution, I don't have the info from the list created on the first round.

Comment: @FabioSoares How are you maintaining the current objects? Would you not be losing them as well each time?

Comment: @Sdyess if I use this approach https://www.dotnetperls.com/static-list it works. Thanks. I will also try the answer posed.

Answer (score 0):

```
    static List<HandGesturesStorage> myStogae;

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult ReadsSerial(string sintraining)
    {
        if (myStogae == null)
        {
            myStogae = new List<HandGesturesStorage>();
        }

        int st;

        try
        {
            st = Int32.Parse(sintraining);
            myStogae.Add(new HandGesturesStorage(sintraining));
        }
        catch (FormatException)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Unable to parse '{sintraining}'");
        }
    }

    public class HandGesturesStorage
    {
        public string HandGesture { get; set; }

        public HandGesturesStorage(string sintraining)
        {
            this.HandGesture = sintraining;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Please see if this can help you. However, not sure what you will be returning in your ReadSerial method.